# Is there a query that allows me to see which of my edits have been rolled back?

Tags: support, edits, data-explorer, rollbacks

As I'm a [frequent editor](https://superuser.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all), I sometimes stumble upon posts where I'm sure that I've already edited them. Most of the time, I see that my edit has been rolled back.

Now, the reasons for these rollbacks might vary, but I'd like to have a way to see them, because:

- Maybe a new user didn't know how the revision system works and rolled back the edit to add details. I'd like to give the user a short introduction about how editing works here.
- Maybe a user had some objections, but failed to tell me. I'd like to know the specific reasons so I can improve or solve any open issues.

Anyway, is there a Data.SE query that would allow me to list these edits (or, the post that was affected)? I couldn't find any, and I probably can't construct a query like this on my own.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any such query, and I don't think one would be very useful. The problem with using SEDE in this case is that the data dumps can be up to three months old. For many questions, editors will stop paying attention after just a few days, let alone months. They may forget why they made particular edits, or disappear entirely.

It would be much more useful, with respect to your goals, for users to get notifications of rollbacks to posts they've edited. Of course, it would take some effort by the team to implement that. I'm afraid that it would lead to petty arguments and edit wars more often than constructive discussion, too.

Comment: Oh, you are of course right. I forgot that recent data isn't included, which kinda defeats the purpose. I'll look for a feature request.

Answer (score 2):

While I can see the utility of such a feature from your point of view, I honestly think that this will make edit wars all too common. Believe it or not, some new users who are not accustomed to their posts being edited will rollback changes made in good faith.

I'm all for educating them and those who make incorrect edits, but I think that implementing this feature might make the editors unwittingly fall into the trap of back-and-forth edits. It's only human nature to be curious (and perhaps slightly peeved if you believe you made a very good edit) and poke further. It's only natural to insist on being given reasons for rollbacks and I do not see this ending constructively in the long run.

I think the current system handles it well enough. If the OP rolls back any changes, the post is again bumped up and fresh eyes (perhaps yours again) will see the post and

1. inform the user about editing policies on SO/SE
2. rollback the changes to a previous revision
3. improve the post

Perhaps point 1 doesn't happen as often as you'd want, but that's the community's problem. A single user cannot fix that.

Comment: Yes, you have a valid point there. I can definitely imagine users feeling personally insulted when their edits are rolled back. At the rate of questions SU gets, for example, it might be possible to spot this (as you mentioned). The whole thing is not something I really *need*, and I begin to understand why a feature like this isn't yet implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is possible.

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer keeps edits and rollbacks in the PostHistory table. Edits of Tile, body and Tags are stored as PostHistoryTypeIds 4, 5 and 6. Rollbacks are stored as 7, 8 and 9. For each event a creationdate is stored so that allows us to find if there were rollbacks after you made an edit. However, you can rollback to any revision, not necessarily to a revision you made. Luckily the Revision guid that is rolledback is stored in the Comment. With some SQL Like fu we can relate those records as well.

Here is [the actual query](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/1284238?UserId=48078)

```
select ph.postid as [Post Link]
     , ph.creationdate
     , rb.creationdate [rollback date]
     , rb.userid as [User Link]
from posthistory ph
inner join 
( select *
  from posthistory
  where posthistorytypeid in (7,8,9)              -- rollback title, body, tags
) rb on rb.postid = ph.postid
    and rb.posthistorytypeid = ph.posthistorytypeid + 3 -- match eventtypes
    and rb.creationdate > ph.creationdate              -- only newer events
where ph.userid = ##userid:int?48078##
and ph.posthistorytypeid in (4,5,6)
-- revisions before that made by the user
and exists 
( select *
  from posthistory
  where postid = ph.postid
  and creationdate < ph.creationdate
  and rb.comment like concat(
                     'Rollback to [[]'
                    , revisionGUID
                    ,']%') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI 
                    )
```

When run today you have a whopping 55 cases where there has been a rollback to a revision that is prior to your edit.

Due to lack of coffee I initially solved a different question. Which was: Which posts had rollbacks to a revision I made.

That is second resultset in the query and this is what it looks like:

```
select ph.postid as [Post Link]
     , ph.creationdate
     , rb.creationdate [rollback date]
     , rb.userid as [User Link]
from posthistory ph
inner join 
( select *
  from posthistory
  where posthistorytypeid in (7,8,9)              -- rollback title, body, tags
) rb on rb.postid = ph.postid
    and rb.posthistorytypeid = ph.posthistorytypeid + 3 -- match eventtypes
    and rb.creationdate > ph.creationdate              -- only newer events
    -- is it the revision
    and rb.comment like concat(
                     'Rollback to [[]'
                    , ph.revisionGUID
                    ,']%') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI 
where ph.userid = ##userid:int?48078##
and ph.posthistorytypeid in (4,5,6)
```

You had 71 of such cases.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).